# How to make a small-sized installer for Windows?

Tags: windows, installation

I made **25**KB exe file with [installsimple](http://www.installsimple.com/),
and **28**KB exe file with [7-zip sfx module](https://sourceforge.net/p/sevenzip/discussion/45797/thread/233f5efd/?limit=25)

But i believe what installer can be smaller for several 1-2KB files

### **What i need from installer**:

- one executable file for deploy
- smallest possible size of result exe file
- launch my program after install
- silent work - dont show any windows

### What will be great(but **optional**):

- change icon of install exe file

Comment: also i compile simple application with [PellesC c-compiler for windows](http://www.pellesc.de/index.php%3Fpage%3Ddownload) and it make 26KB exe-file **:(**

Comment: This sounds a bit "theoretical". What is the use-case scenario?